# JSONP не работает

Tags: javascript, jquery

Отправляю запрос следующим образом:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Адрес сайта (кроссдоменный запрос)',
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

В ответ получаю **JSON**: **{TEST: "TEST_MESSAGE"}**

Но в консоли браузера пишет: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :**

Как решить данную проблему и получить уже ответ в виде JSON, ну а потом соответственно распарсить его?

**Запрос кросдоменный**

Comment: Если это дословный ответ, то это не JSON и не JSONP. А кто-то обещал что сервер умеет отдавать jsonp?

Comment: Я задал конкретный вопрос... Сервер отдает только это: {TEST: "TEST_MESSAGE"}, как мне эту строку получить, и скажем... с помощью алерта вывести?

Comment: Если действительно только это, то никак. Это не JSONP. Нужно настраивать сервер, что бы он отдавал JSONP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Небольшое отступление**

JSONP предполагает, что данные, возвращаемые с сервера оборачиваются в специальную функцию, имя которой передается на сервер в параметре `callback`.

Например, если клиент отправил на сервер JSONP запрос

```
GET www.example.com/something.php?callback=foo123
```

То сервер должен вернуть вот такой документ:

```
foo123({"test": "data"});
```

<sub>обратите внимание на функицю `foo123`</sub>

---

Если говорить о вашей проблеме, то конструкция

```
{TEST: "TEST_MESSAGE"}
```

является корректным JSON сообщением, однако это не JSONP (нет оборачивающей функции).

Как следствие, единственный способ решить вашу проблему -- дорабатывать ответ сервера.